# Objective c: Protocol + Delegate to pass data back from Login form in a Modal View to an tab bar controller view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios4, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm developing a tab bar based app for iPhone.
The flow is the following: when the app runs, I throw up the modal view with the login form:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
tabBarController.delegate = self;

// Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display. 
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self addTabBarArrow];

LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES; }
```

In the log in modal view LoginViewController.h (child) I've got a protocol implemented:

```
@protocol PassUserInfoDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) passUserInfo: (NSString *)string;
@end
```

When the user fills out the form, I create a NSURLConnection, and in the connectionDidFinishLoading method I get the user values from an JSON request:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSString *respuestaServidor = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.responseData = nil;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [respuestaServidor JSONValue];
idJson = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *user_loginJson = [dictionary objectForKey:@"user_login"];

if ([idJson isEqualToString:@"null"] && [user_loginJson isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
    NSLog(@"Login incorrecto");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Procedo a loguear usuario");
}
[indicator stopAnimating];
[indicator release];
}
```

In HomeViewController.h (parent) I've got the delegation:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <PassUserInfoDelegate> {
LoginViewController *protocolTest;
IBOutlet UILabel *nombreUsuario;
NSString *usuario;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nombreUsuario;
@property (copy) NSString *usuario;

- (void) passUserInfo:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

and in the HomeViewController.m I implement the Protocol method:

```
- (void) passUserInfo:(NSString *)jSonString
{
    userName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", jSonString];
}
```

and in the viewDidAppear method I call the loginSuccess method implemented in the LoginViewController class

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
protocolTest = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[protocolTest setDelegate:self];
[protocolTest loginSuccess];
}
```

loginSuccess method implemented in the LoginViewController class:

```
- (void)loginSuccess
{
    [[self delegate] passUserInfo:idJson];
}
```

and it should pass the idJson value to the HomeViewController (parent).
The problem is that when I dismiss the modal view form, the idJson value is "NIL", so then in the HomeViewController I can't get this value. If I make this instead:

```
[[self delegate] passUserInfo:@"hello"];
```

I get the hello string in the HomeViewController (parent)
What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that instead of using the existing LoginViewController that has the actual data. Your viewWillAppear is creating a new one that never made the connection and getting its empty data.

First in the app delegate, you need to set your `HomeViewController` (the one in the tabbar) as the delegate to the `LoginViewController` that you're presenting.

Then, from `connectionDidFinishLoading:` you should be calling the `[delegate passUserInfo:idJson];` to inform the `HomeVC` that the login screen got data. 
You `HomeVC`'s `passUserInfo:` method should probably dismiss the `LoginVC` with `[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` (Since the login view was presented from the tabbar controller).

Comment: Thanks @thelaws!! I solved the first part, I followed your steps and I solved the idJson value thing! Now I can get the idJson value in the passUserInfo method. What is not working is the last thing, dismissing the modal view from the passUserInfo method. It just doesn't dismiss the view, and Xcode doesn't throw up any debug error...

Comment: Wouldn't be better to dismiss the modal view after calling the passUserInfo method from the loginVC's connectionDidFinishLoading method?

Comment: I don't the the LoginVC should have an instance of the tabbarcontroller, which it needs to dismiss. You could probably present the loginvc from the homevc so that you can dismiss it easily.